# Global State for React

Tags: reactjs, state

Pardon my ignorance.  I am still pretty new to React.  Is there anything particularly wrong with storing certain values in the state of the App component and passing a prop to child components that allows them to set the state of App?  Of course I wouldn't use it to store all of the state for child components, just certain values I want available everywhere.

Comment: This is what Redux and other libaries can do for you effectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **React-context** or **Redux**, for example, redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps (something like a global state, which could be accessed all over the project)

check it here https://redux.js.org/

Comment: I ended up using useContext but then I ended up having way too many UI updates (a problem which even my duct-taped solution from before didnt have) so I had to use React.memo to prevent that.  I think thats the solution I like the best.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial)/[react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [recoil](https://recoiljs.org/). These are libraries which are made to handle global state (or state which is needed in multiple places).

However if your app is very small and does not have much state it is imo fine to keep that state in the `App` component. Just make sure that you'll look for alternatives once you application grows as it isn't very performant or readbable to do so in bigger projects.

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial) was/is considered the go to state management library for react applications by many. It [integrates great with react](https://react-redux.js.org/) and is very mature. I would go for it if you expect your application to have a complex global state or become more and more complex over time. There are also great companion libraries available. For example  [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) if you want to handle side effects or [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) if you want to persist you apps state.

[Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) is still pretty new and especially made for react apps. Even though it is only around for a few months you can probably expect it to develop nicely as it is backed and used by facebook. Arguably it is the more performant and easier to get into choice, but you'll probably find less guides and tutorials due to its novelty.

If you only have a few values you could also just use [reacts context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Ok, to be clear I wouldn't put the state of all the child components in 1 place, this would just be for certain variables I want available everywhere.  The child components would still maintain their own state but variables like isLoggedIn for example would be available everywhere.  

Also, I will definitely do my homework on Redux and Recoil.  Have you used Recoil?  What did you think of it?  I only haven't tried to learn Redux because I have heard there is a learning curve with it but I suppose I need to at least be familiar with it if i'm going to work on a development team eventually.

Comment: That sounds like a situation which would be a good fit for reacts context. Usually you'd put things which are needed throughout the whole application and aren't subject to frequent changes into the context (like a theme or translations).

Comment: I haven't used recoil myself yet, but we recently started experimenting with it for some small fun projects and from what I've seen it works great and is very easy to adapt. About redux: if you have the time you should definitely look into it. Even if you end up not using it in the end, the concept and idea behind redux is a great way to learn about global state management, the issues developers usually face and how they can be overcome.

Comment: You were right about React Context.  I like it alot and I also use React.memo to control the UI updates.  I had tried Recoil and I had the same issue with the UI updates so I stuck with Context because I like the syntax better.

Comment: Great that it fits your use case! For a lot of web apps it is a good fit. You'll know when an app could use a state management library when it becomes that complex that you start to rebuild one :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, React-context or Redux, both of them works as you want

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly right to do so in some cases, other options are using [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)

For a simple value your first option is ok, if you need to store more complicated values and need to update them frequently I'd suggest using any of the other options.

They both have some significant learning and setup curve though.

Comment: Yes, there is a pretty new framework which is easier to learn than redux... I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how deep is your application tree. If it is a very simple app, you can get away with just using React state. If it is something more complex (like 3 or more levels deep), I suggest to use React Context (for simple values) or Redux for more complex actions.